# Angular fullCalendar Integration Not Show current date after loading

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular11

I follow below link to install FullCalendar in angular project

[Angular fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular)

I Integrated Angular FullCalendar to show date .When I load it does not show calendar .It only
show month panel. After click preview or next button it show the Date

here is the calendar option I set

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
    eventClick: this.handleEvetClick.bind(this),
    initialDate: new Date(),
    
    height: 500,
    
  };
```

we embedded calendar following code

```
<div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
 <full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
<div>
```

here is the screenshot after loading

[image: screen shot of Calendar After loading]

after Click the preview or next button

[image: screenshot after Click the preview or next button]

I seek your help to solve this problem and need to customize initial date when loading

(that is this month is July 2021 i need to load calendar from December)

like above i need to customize initial date dynamically when loading

Comment: Did you forget to load some of the CSS? Or do you have other CSS in your page which interferes with fullCalendar? Provide a [mre] please.

Comment: no .i changed the color and  add preview and next button icon. other themes are default

Comment: Ok. Like I said then we'll need sufficient code and data to be able to reproduce the error. What you've shown so far, by itself, would not cause this.

Comment: Well, you tell me... Put it this way: If I was to take only the code you've provided, and run it, would it demonstrate your problem? If not, then go through your code and add more bits to your sample until it would. Again, the [mre] article explains what you need to do.

Comment: this is a common initial loading problem in Version 5.8.0.After loading if we adjust the size of calendar we can view the calendar as shown in  image 2. Are there any function to free size the calendar to call  after loading? 
events Are added.

Comment: You can call `render()` anytime yes. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-render

Comment: could you please give me a solution to resize the fulcalendar after loading

Comment: render() should redraw the calendar and correct any visual glitches such as those in your screenshot. Have you tried it? Other than that, maybe have a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing

Comment: yes i did not solved

Comment: Ok so please look at the sizing documentation. There are some functions there which might help you.

Comment: yes there is a windowResize  callback

Comment: Did that solve your problem then?

Comment: no i don't know  how to call windowResize callback

Comment: It's a callback, so you would use it similar to the dateClick and eventClick callbacks you've defined in your code already.

Comment: But I was expecting you'd maybe want to call the updateSize() _method_ actually, so you can pro-actively force the calendar to change size to correct the glitch. However, I may have misunderstood the situation as some of your descriptions are quite vague.

Comment: when i change the height of calendar while loading it resize the height from initialized size but not show the calendar
thank you

Comment: As mentioned previously, if you have a specific issue when using some particular code please update your question to show a [mre] of the usage of that code which would demonstrate the problem. Without such information in detail, we can only guess what the exact issue is.